# How to hot-reload ReactJS build with gulp and browserify?

Tags: reactjs, browserify, webpack

I know, hot-reload developed for webpack initially. 
I don't want to use webpack, because of it's terrible config and bunch of other reasons. The only advantage in webpack is hot-reload for ReactJS.

Is there way to make my browserify + gulp build hot reload react webapp?

Thank you for your time!

Comment: The accepted answer is not hot reloading. `watchify` just rebundles on file change. That doesn't have anything to do with changing out modules within a currently loaded app in the browser.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can discover [watchify](https://github.com/substack/watchify).

Just wrap your browserify command with watchify:

```
watchify(browserify(options))
```

Answer (score 3):

If you're looking to hot-reload react components (updating js without a page reload) you can use [livereactreload](https://github.com/milankinen/livereactload) which [@gaeron](https://github.com/gaearon) recommends as an alternative to [react-hot-loader](https://github.com/gaearon/react-hot-loader) for browserify users.

Though if/when you have some time you can replace browserify with webpack and integrate it with your existing gulp build process if you like the webpack way of doing things.

Comment: +1 for the answer, although the OP explicitly stated that he / she doesn't like *the webpack way of doing things*.